# Calculate with multiple conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a summarized table from a larger table with 2 columns, Year and QTY. I would like to add a 3rd column that shows the average QTY from 2020-2022. I have this measure but it is returning only blanks. I'm looking for it to return 1 value.

The Column:

```
3_Year_line =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Table[Qty] ),
    YEAR ( Table[Year] ) = 2020,
    YEAR ( Table[Year] ) = 2021,
    YEAR ( Table[Year] ) = 2022
) / 3
```

Would anyone have an idea why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
3_Year_line = 
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGE ( 'Table'[Qty] ),
    'Table'[Year] = 2020 
    || 'Table'[Year] = 2021
    || 'Table'[Year] = 2022
)
```

Note that

- `YEAR(<date>)` expects a date, not an integer
- `CALCULATE(<expression>, <filter1>, <filter2>)` evaluates the filters using AND, not OR